# Best way to wait for DOM elements to load/change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I'm working with youtube DOM atm and I'm wondering if there are any good ways to wait for all the youtube videos to render in before I run my code.

I'm using jquery document ready code now and when I'm testing my code on bad computers with 800mhz cpu then my code only runs on some of the DOM objects.

```
const continuation_watch = $("ytd-watch-next-secondary-results-renderer.style-scope.ytd-watch") 
    continuation_watch.on("yt-load-next-continuation", event=>{                     
        setTimeout(()=>{
            <run my code>

        }, 1000)
    })
```

With the code above i'm bascially running my code after youtube loads in more video's and Im using a setTimeout to wait for those videos to be ready before I run my code. Are there any better way's doing this w.o using a setTimeout?

Comment: Can you use `.ready()` or `.on("ready")` type event trigger?

Comment: I tried, but the document or dom is already ready. After my event code runs then I think youtube uses get to get in the rest of the videos.

Comment: If youtube is performing a HTTP command, you should be able to see this in the Networking tab of your development tools. If this is the case, you can look for HTTP Responses and use this as a trigger.

Comment: Yeah it does, but the response is still faster than the new rendered video's, atm I'm trying to look at mutationobserver and see if I can make it work with this.